# Apache pig about sort top n

Tags: apache-pig

Recently i try to use pig to sort some data, and following is my script to data order by count (for example i want to find top 3) :

```
in = load 'data.txt';
split = foreach in generate flatten(TOKENIZE((chararray)$0)) as tmp;
C = group split by tmp;
result = foreach C generate group, COUNT(split) as cnt;
des = ORDER result BY cnt DESC;
fin = LIMIT des 3;
```

And then output just like:

```
A,10
B,9
C,8
```

But if we have another data which count is also 8, it can't be output. In detail, when i type DUMP des, contents like following:

```
A,10
B,9
C,8
D,8
E,8
F,7
.
.
```

If i want to output top 3, it also need to include D,8 E,8 in the result, but LIMIT in pig script language can't do it. Does someone have experience deal with the problem by using pig language, or must write an UDF function to handle it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Limit` will not work in your case, you have to use `RANK` and `FILTER` operator.

**data.txt**

```
A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A,A
B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B,B
C,C,C,C,C,C,C,C
D,D,D,D,D,D,D,D
E,E,E,E,E,E,E,E
F,F,F,F,F,F,F
```

**PigScript:**

```
in = load 'data.txt';
sp = foreach in generate flatten(TOKENIZE((chararray)$0)) as tmp;
C = group sp by tmp;
result = foreach C generate group, COUNT(sp) as cnt;
myrank = RANK result BY cnt DESC DENSE;
top3 = FILTER myrank BY rank_result<=3;
finalOutput = FOREACH top3 GENERATE group,cnt;
DUMP finalOutput;
```

**Output:**

```
(A,10)
(B,9)
(C,8)
(D,8)
(E,8)
```

Comment: the parameter : rank_result isn't exist , does it use the parameter result?

Comment: Its hidden parameter of relation myrank, you can see the parameter by using describe command. DESCRIBE myrank; it will show you.